# Creating a class that stores all objects created in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

So I created three class called "Address", "Job" and "Person" with "Person" being my primary class. I test these by:

```
Address person2Address = new Address(1054, "Pico St", "Los Angeles", "CA", "97556");
    Address person2JobAddress = new Address(5435, "James St", "New York", "NY", "56565");
    ArrayList<String> person2Phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    person2Phone.add("555-555-55");
    Job person2Job = new Job("Mechanic", 35000.00, person2JobAddress);
    Person person2 = new Person("Rollan Tico", "New York", 'M', person2Address, person2Job, person2Phone);
    System.out.println(person2.toString());
```

They print everything correctly. Now, this is where I am stuck. How would I create a different class called Persons that stores each Person created in a ArrayList? Would there be any constrcunert? I know that an Arrayist is created by `ArrayList<Person> List = new ArrayList<Person>();`, but got a feeling I am missing something.

Comment: You don't need a separate class.  Assuming you're looking for an immutable list, you can use `List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(person1, person2, ...);`

Comment: @JacobG. `Arrays.asList()` is not immutable, just fixed-size.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Collection like

`Collection<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
persons.add(person2);`

Or in some case, like JSON serialization you cannot seralize a list as the root element. so,

```
import java.util.*

public class Persons {

  private Collection<Person> persons;

  //If you want the clients to have flexibility to choose the implementation of persons collection.
  //Else, hide this constructor and create the persons collection in this class only.
  public Persons(Collection<Person> persons) {
    this.persons = persons;
  }

  public void addPerson(Person person) {
   persons.add(person);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't i pass arraylist directly :/ ? Can u elaborate please why did u use collection if one can do it with Arraylist as well @harivis

Comment: Yes, you can. 
`List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>(); 
personList.add(person1); //and so on..
Persons persons = new Persons(personList);`
You do not need this new class if you are well off with just having a Collection<Person> field.

Comment: ohk thanx :) so i don't need to type .add everytime to add new person if i use collectionlist ,right? @harivis +1

Answer (score 0):

If you create a class for an object like `Person`, you don't need to create a `Persons` class just to store multiple `Person` objects. Unless you have to define operations which involves multiple `Person` Objects, like for example a `Group` class with operations performed on group pf persons, in which case creating a `Persons` or `Group` class makes sense. In your case I would assume you just need to store multiple `Person` objects and for that `ArrayList<Person>` will suffice.

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
persons.add(new Person(.....)); //add Person
.
.
Person person1=persons.get(1); //get Person by index
```